# Delete Plugin CRM Dynamics - when an entity is deleted will the associated notes delete automatically?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a custom bill entity and a row of bill data in this entity has an associated note pdf. When service.Delete is called in a plugin on the bill guid will the associated note also be deleted (ie a cascading delete)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the cascade delete behaviour is handled by the system configuration, not by a plugin.
if you google something like "configure cascade delete dynamics crm" you can find additional results to help you understand it.

If you have a specific scenario where the cascade is not applicable or you want to perform some specific logic (like saving the attachments to another entity prior the deletion) then you need to be more specific, stackoverflow is a community focused on technical aspects in forms of Q&A, there is also Dynamics Community Forums for more generic questions regarding Microsoft Dynamics.

Comment: Thanks Guido - we looked into this and it has worked out for us. many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Like Guido explained this is taken care by Relationship behavior between those two entities. [Read more](https://carldesouza.com/entity-relationships-in-dynamics-365/) .

Lets take this OOB relationship between Appointment and Note - this has "Parental" behavior and Delete is set to 'Cascade All"

[image]

You have a choice to switch the behavior to "Configurable cascading" but I see a blocker that Delete behavior cannot be changed and its greyed out.

[image]

Usually for a custom relationship or wherever it is allowed, we can switch the Delete option to have "Remove Link". In this case - since it is not allowing, you may have to stop the Note deletion and do this delink yourself in a Note pre-Delete plugin.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Arun - we looked into this and it has worked out for us. I can only give 1 green tick so I gave it to Guido but many thanks to you and for the extra detail.

Comment: @JamesMarcO'Sullivan: no worries, happy to help :)